# How to search for a specific word NOT followed by another specific word in solr?

Tags: regex, solr

What i'm trying to do is to only get results for "foo" when is not followed by "bar".
I tried using regex following this [link](https://1opensourcelover.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/solr-regex-tutorial/) like this: name:/foo(?!\s+bar)/ but i'm not getting any result.
Is there another way to do that? Or is my regex wrong?

edit: MatsLindh comment works, but i'm losing every result where i have BOTH foo and foo bar in a together (ex. "foo ababa foo bar"). I want to filter out ONLY the results that have just foo followed by bar, without any other occurrence of foo.

Comment: so , what about [this](https://regex101.com/r/rpbI2n/6)

Comment: The regex is working, but i'm still not getting any result from the solr console. I'm not sure about which expressions are accepted by solr.

Comment: How about performing a negative match against documents that contain the phrase? `q=*:* -field:"foo bar"` - My guess is that the regex will match against tokens, and if your field is being processed (i.e. tokenized on whitespace or similar), it won't see both both terms at the same time.

Comment: @MatsLindh this worked, thanks. You should post that as an answer, as i can't upvote your comment.

Comment: Sorry @MatsLindh, i have edited my question to add more details. Your solution works but i'm missing some results, so it's not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the right way is to use ComplexPhraseQueryParser:
`{!complexphrase df=name}"foo -bar"`

I don't think this is well documented, so i had to do a bit of research and trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to filter your results

`q=*:*&fq=-name:"foo bar"`

Note that, you should not do tokenizer for filed `name` or only use `solr.StrField` for this filed.

If you want do tokenizer for this field, you can ref `copyFiled`.

```
<field name="copyName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
<copyField source="name" dest="copyName" />
```

Comment: That doesn't work though, it's the same as @MatsLindh solution, i'm losing the results where i have both foo and foo bar together. I want to filter out results where i have ONLY foo followed by bar.

Comment: You should list some examples for your question, like : (foo bar , foo bar car, foo foo bar, car foo bar, bar foo bar ...). Which cases you want to filter out and which cases you want to return.